# i made a php file that let people follow each other

Tags: php, mysql

I made this PHP page to let people follow each other it takes the following user id from the table users and when the logged-in user presses follow, the action should be saved in followers table.

```
followers table
    id  int
    user_id int
    follower-id int

users table
    email varchar
    id int
    username varchar
    password varchar
```

I am getting this error

> :Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'follower' in
>   'field list'' in C:\socialnetwork\classes\DB.php:12 Stack trace: #0
>   C:socialnetwork\classes\DB.php(12): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1
>   C:\Users\Karim\Desktop\socialnetwork\profile.php(17):
>   DB::query('SELECT follower...', Array) #2 {main} thrown in
>   C:socialnetwork\classes\DB.php on line 12

Thank you for your time.

```
<?php
include('./classes/DB.php');
include('./classes/Login.php');
$username = "";

if (isset($_GET['username'])) {
        if (DB::query('SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=:username', array(':username'=>$_GET['username']))) {
                $username = DB::query('SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=:username', array(':username'=>$_GET['username']))[0]['username'];
                if (isset($_POST['follow'])) {



                        $userid = DB::query('SELECT id FROM users WHERE username=:username', array(':username'=>$_GET['username']))[0]['id'];
                        $followerid = Login::isLoggedIn();


                        if (!DB::query('SELECT follower-id FROM `followers` WHERE user_id=:user_id', array(':user_id'=>$userid))) {
                                DB::query('INSERT INTO followers VALUES (null, :user_id, :follower-id)', array(':user_id'=>$userid, ':follower-id'=>(int)$followerid));
                        } else {
                                echo 'Already following!';
                        }
                }
        } else {
                die('User not found!');
        }
}
?>

<h1><?php echo $username; ?>'s Profile</h1>
<form action="profile.php?username=<?php echo $username; ?>" method="post">
        <input type="submit" name="follow" value="Follow">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hyphens, even though not disallowed, can cause problems in column names.

In order to make it work you have to enclose the name of the column with back-ticks:

```
SELECT `follower-id` FROM
```

As MySQL documentation confirms:

> **Permitted characters in unquoted identifiers:**
>
> ASCII: [0-9,a-z,A-Z$_] (basic Latin letters, digits 0-9, dollar,
>   underscore)
>
> Extended: U+0080 .. U+FFFF
>
> **Permitted characters in quoted identifiers include the full Unicode
>   Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP), except U+0000:**
>
> ASCII: U+0001 .. U+007F
>
> Extended: U+0080 .. U+FFFF

ASCII code for dash `-` is 45, which is within the "quoted identifiers" ASCII range

Comment: thank you for your time it gave my another error Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'follower-id'

Comment: What's the full error, the value you're trying to insert, and data types of all the fields?

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'follower-id' at row 1' in C:\Users\Karim\Desktop\socialnetwork\classes\DB.php:12 Stack trace: #0 C:\Users\Karim\Desktop\socialnetwork\classes\DB.php(12): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 C:\Users\Karim\Desktop\socialnetwork\profile.php(19): DB::query('INSERT INTO fol...', Array) #2 {main} thrown in C:\Users\Karim\Desktop\socialnetwork\classes\DB.php on line 12

Comment: datatype id userid follower id : int user table : id int

Comment: `$followerid` seems to be of a boolean type, since it's a result of `Login::isLoggedIn();` which I'm assuming returns `true/false`. Maybe try a conversion like this `':follower-id'=>(int)$followerid`

Comment: that didn't work i don't know what it means by follower column not found i didn't mention follower in my php or sql 
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'follower' in 'field list'' in C:\Users\Karim\Desktop\socialnetwork\classes\DB.php:12 Stack trace: #0 C:\Users\Karim\Desktop\socialnetwork\classes\DB.php(12): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 C:\Users\Karim\Desktop\socialnetwork\profile.php(17): DB::query('SELECT follower...', Array) #2 {main} thrown in C:\Users\Karim\Desktop\socialnetwork\classes\DB.php on line 12

Comment: Have you got the back ticks around the reference to your `follower-id` column in that `SELECT` statement on the line 17th?

Comment: Can you edit your original question add add the most current version of the query you're running?

Comment: my laptop lost power i need 30 min to get back home and i will edit my post thank you for your time :)